# phpMyAdmin - Error: relational features are disabled

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

When I want to create a relation between two tables in designer mode with phpMyAdmin 4.3.8, it gives me an error saying: Error: relational features are disabled!
When I try it with 4.1.4, it works just fine.
I can't seem to find where I should change the settings to be able to create relations in designer mode.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 42):

Convert your table/db engine to InnoDB using

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: did the trick for me when I created a new table after updating PMA

Comment: It is funny how many times I ended up in this very question. And this very effective answer.

Comment: @JoséGonzález glad you got help.

Comment: My tables are already InnoDB, is there another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was because I didn't have a database on the mysql server for pypMyAdmin settings.

So you may need to update your PMA settings database or create one...

There is a guide on how to do it [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Configuration_storage)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error I didn't create any PMA Users I just upgraded the version of phpmyadmin to latest version and everything worked just fine

here is the link for downloading and for me it was 4.6.0

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

and for me I was working on MAMP Pro so I just did :

- I stopped the server (MAMP Pro).
- I copied the file (config.inc.php) from the old phpmyadmin folder to the new one.
- I replaced the older version with the new one in ("/Applications/MAMP/bin/").
- I copied the same new version folder to ("/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/") because I am working with MAMP Pro not MAMP.
- And then I restarted the server (MAMP Pro ) and everything worked just fine.

I hope it will work for you as well.