# phpmyadmin Error: Relational features are disabled

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

When I try and create a relationship between two tables I get the error -

> "Relational features are disabled".

I've seen that updating phpmyadmin could possibly solve the issue, but I don't have access to do this. I contacted hostgator and they say I'm unable to do this and I would have to upgrade to a different plan in order to upgrade phpmyadmin.

I'm currently running version 4.3.8.

Is there any other fix for this error to allow relationships to be created between tables?

Comment: I'm not sure an upgrade is going to fix the problem. What storage type are the tables you're trying to use for the relations? As long as you have a web space that allows you to run PHP files, you can install your own phpMyAdmin to your web root despite your host's statement that they can't upgrade it.

Comment: Hi there is a sugesstion right here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218491/phpmyadmin-error-relational-features-are-disabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyAdmin - Error: relational features are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218491/phpmyadmin-error-relational-features-are-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your table/db engine to InnoDB with this query :
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;